# WEB-INF/web.xml not being created

Tags: tomcat, solr, cpanel

I'm attempting to use solr 4.2 with a cPanel installation of Tomcat 7. Solr works fine, except I'm attempting to add security features. To do that I need to edit the web.xml file. You should be able to navigate to the created directory

`/var/lib/easy-tomcat7/webapps/solr/WEB-INF/web.xml`

But the problem is that the "solr" directory is not automatically being created as it should. It appears in the tomcat manager, and I can access and run solr perfectly fine, but I can't find the directory. I even ran a

```
find / -name web.xml
```

and that returned nothing for solr. I also even tried running,

```
find / -name admin.html
```

which also returned nothing relevant.

Why is this directory not being created? I tried manually creating it and it doesn't read it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to create create the app through the Tomcat 7 manager panel. Creating the app through that panel correctly adds the folders. After that you must properly set the path in the "" part of the newly created web.xml.

Still not sure what was wrong the last approach, it worked fine with Tomcat 6. Switching to cPanel and Tomcat 7 must have something to do with it.